# Using acts-as-taggable-on with jQuery-tokenInput plugin for multiple taggable fields

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-tokeninput, act-as-taggable-on

I'm having trouble with using token input plugin with acts-as-taggable-on gem to save tags for custom tag_list. Now, I have `acts_as_taggable_on :skills` in `User.rb`, so I want to add tags to skill_list. Currently, I'm seeing a server log `skill_tokens"=>"161"` in the parameters, so I believe the form is sending a tag id, but when I try `user.skills` or `user.taggings` in the console, it won't show anything.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I need your help. Anythings helps, thank you!

> User.rb

```
has_many :taggings, as: :taggable, dependent: :destroy
has_many :tags, through: :taggings

attr_accessor :skill_tokens

acts_as_tagger
acts_as_taggable
acts_as_taggable_on :skills
```

> UserController

```
def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(
  :skill_tokens,
  :skill_list: []
)
end

def load_tags
@user = User.new
@tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: tokens(params[:q]) } # get result from tokens method
end
end

# return search result for tags
def tokens(query)
 @tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all
 @tags = @tags.where('name Ilike ?', "%#{params[:q]}%")
 if @tags.empty?
   [{ id: "<<<#{query}>>>", name: "Add: \"#{query}\"" }]
 else
   @tags
 end
end

def load_categories
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

> Here's my jQuery code

`$('#user_skill_tokens').tokenInput '/signup.json '
    tokenValue: 'user[skill_list][]'
    theme: 'facebook'`

> Here's the form in slim

```
 = f.label :skill_tokens, "Tag List"
 = f.text_field :skill_tokens
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what is "going wrong" -- Are you getting errors? Not seeing something you should? (if so, what do you expect to see?) Seeing something you shouldn't? Etc.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that when I try "user.skills" or "user.taggings" to confirm if the data is saved to the databse, it's shows nothing. The data is not saved to the database even the parameter is sending.

Comment: I don't think you need attr_accessor, it is in your strong parameters. Also isn't name the default tokenvalue?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I added some code to my coffee script as below:

```
$('#user_skill_tokens').tokenInput '/signup.json '
  tokenValue: 'name'
  theme: 'facebook
```

Comment: Your code is working for you? Can you please edit your route in ?